# Converting string to string[] on Method.Invoke()

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a `Dictionary<string, Delegate> commands` with my delegate taking two strings and a string[] as params.

I'm entering a command in a Console Application:

```
:adduser username email@email.com Firstname Middlename Lastname
```

where everything is converted to an array of strings (size 6). I then do

```
list[3] = string.Join(" ", input, 3, 3);
list.RemoveRange(4, list.Count - 4);
```

to convert Firstname, Middlename, and Lastname into a single string, so that my array looks like this:

`input[0]`: `:adduser`

`input[1]`: `:username`

`input[2]`: `:email@email.com`

`input[3]`: `:Firstname Middlename Lastname`

I then try to call `commands[input[0]].Method.Invoke(this, list.Skip(1).ToArray<object>());`, but it results in an ArgumentException with the message

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.

I'm a bit lost, as I don't really know what's wrong.
I'd appreaciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps did mean

```
commands[input[0]].Method.Invoke(this, new object[] { list[0], list[1], list.Skip(2).ToArray()});
```

That should match your delegates signature which expect 3 arguments. Your error message indicates that your list is passed as first argument. The reason is that you must pass the other arguments as an object array where the first item is arg1, the second is arg2, ....

Answer (score 1):

[`Method.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) takes an array of parameters after the instance.  When you have to pass an array as a single parameter, you need to wrap it in an `object[]`. Otherwise it gets interpreted as a set of parameters to the delegate:

```
commands[input[0]].Method.Invoke(this, new object[] {list.Skip(1).ToArray()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `list[3] = string.Join(" ", input, 3, 3);`. If your signature is in fact `(string user, string mail, string[] names)` you can not call it with 3 strings.

My proposal:

```
list[3] = input.Skip(3).Take(3).ToArray();
```

PS: Regarding design I do not recommend recycling the list object but rather create a dedicated object that carries the arguments.